# frame.append() method deprecated

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

```
import os
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si

tickers = ["aapl","msft","fb"]
for ticker in tickers:
    try:
        quote = si.get_quote_table(ticker)
        price = (quote["Quote Price"])
        print (ticker, price)
        
    except:
        pass
```

When running this piece of code I get this error:

`FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.`

Can someone tell me how to adapt the code?

Comment: Because you aren't using pandas, this looks like an issue with the `yahoo_fin` module. There's an open GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/atreadw1492/yahoo_fin/issues/90) about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you aren't using pandas, this looks like an issue with the `yahoo_fin` module. There's an open GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/atreadw1492/yahoo_fin/issues/90) about it.

It looks like [lines 295, 302, and 336 of *stock_info.py*](https://github.com/atreadw1492/yahoo_fin/blob/master/yahoo_fin/stock_info.py#L295) is the issue in the source code. I've opened a [pull request](https://github.com/atreadw1492/yahoo_fin/pull/99) to fix this. The problematic lines like this:

```
data = tables[0].append(tables[1])
```

and my PR changes them to this

```
data = pd.concat([tables[0], tables[1]])
```

to this fixes the issue. If you are impatient and can't wait for upstream to merge the PR, then you could apply the patch yourself and build from source.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `yahoo_fin` but based on your code and the warning in question, this appears to be something the developers of that library need to change (by using the `concat` method instead of `append`). In the meantime, you can continue to use it as is and ignore the warning or you could always contribute to their codebase, or fork it and make the change for yourself.